# qtip2 sets attributes but doesn't show with jquery on.(mouseover)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, qtip, qtip2

This is the code I use to show the qtips:

```
$(document).on('mouseover', '.sktooltip', function(event) {
    // Bind the qTip within the event handler
    $(this).qtip({
        overwrite: false, // Make sure the tooltip won't be overridden once created
        content: 'ToolTip!',
        target: 'mouse',
        show: {
            event: event.type, // Use the same show event as the one that triggered the event handler
            ready: true // Show the tooltip as soon as it's bound, vital so it shows up the first time you hover!
        }
    }, event); // Pass through our original event to qTip
})

// Store our title attribute in 'oldtitle' attribute instead
.each(function(i) {
    $.attr(this, 'oldtitle', $.attr(this, 'title'));
    this.removeAttribute('title');
});
```

It's basically the same as the one in the docs.

Now, the relevant HTML before I hover over it:

```
<div class="service-block msr">
    <a target="_blank" href="http://google.de">
    <div class="service-image msrc">
        <img rel="254" data-original="123.png" class="sktooltip" src="123.png" style="display: inline;">
    </div></a>
    <h4><a target="_blank" href="http://google.de">Google</a></h4>
    <p>Search Engine</p>
</div>
```

And after:

```
<div class="service-block msr">
    <a target="_blank" href="http://google.de">
    <div class="service-image msrc">
        <img rel="254" data-original="123.png" class="sktooltip" src="123.png" style="display: inline;" data-hasqtip="0" aria-describedby="qtip-0">
    </div></a>
    <h4><a target="_blank" href="http://google.de">Google</a></h4>
    <p>Search engine</p>
</div>
```

As you can see, qtip inserts its attributes in the element but I can't see the the tooltip. What am I missing?

Edit: It does work here but not on my website: http://jsfiddle.net/Dayjay/738nX/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now! I used jquery.isotope which implements an older version of the imagesLoaded plugin, which caused problems with qTip2 . To solve this, simply include the latest imagesLoaded script after the isotope script.